# fputcsv() problem. Textarea isn't saved in one column

Tags: php

Today, I found my limit in data operations knowledge.

I can successfully save input fields as well as textareas by doing this:

```
    $f = fopen($dir, "a");
    fputcsv($f, $content, ";");
    fclose($f);
```

Later on, I can retrieve the data and store it in array by using explode()... or so have I thought!

The problem is in me. I like **BIG** textareas. I am currently making a forum page and I would like to grant my visitors ability to *break the line* when creating a thread.

For instance:

```
 /*
   I break the line by pressing ENTER
   And again
*/
```

This is the code I wrote so far:

let's say, the input from the user looks like this

```
+---------------------------+
| Hello,                    |
| I find this form amazing. |
|                           |
| Can I get a hug?          |
+---------------------------+
```

The user pressed ENTER 3 times making this thread..

```
if(isset($_POST['thread']))
{
   $thread = htmlspecialchars($_POST['thread']);
   $date = date('d.m.Y');

   fclose($e);
   $f = fopen("../data/forum-data/threads.csv", "a");
   $data = array($user, $thread, $date, time(), $mail);
   fputcsv($f, $data, ";", chr(127));
   fclose($f);
   echo '<center><div class="success-box">';
   echo 'SUCCESS!';
   echo '</center></div>';
                    
   $show_forum = true;
   //echo "Username: " . $user . "<br>" . "Email: " . $mail; 
}
```

in my threads.csv file, this is what's been saved:

```
someuser;Hello
I find this form amazing

can I get a hug?;05.12.2021;1638716270; someone@nix.com
```

This is wished:

```
someuser;Hello"< br >"I find this form amazing"< br >""< br >"can I get a hug?;05.12.2021;1638716270;   someone@nix.com
```

I want it to be saved in one row because the data cannot be retrieved at all. For example:

```
$o = fopen(../data/forum-data/threads.csv);
while(!feof($o))
{
  $row = fgets($o, 4096);
  $column = explode(";", $row);
  foreach($column as $element)
  {
    echo $element . "< br >";
  }
}
fclose($o);
```

Now, I assure you. The page is blank. Nothing gets printed out, unless the data is saved in a single row like in example from above. I am open to any solution that features php code. I have no idea about .js whatsoever.

Respectfully Regarding,

I am crying

Comment: did you try fputs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others. Using `str_replace()` is the correct way to replace `\n` or `\r\n` with a different string.

Comment: fputs() does not split individual data, at least not in a .csv file. I am open to any solution, but my task is to use .csv file. I didn't come with str_replace() far, so if someone could suggest anything, that would be pretty cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/str_replace) to replace any `"\r\n"` with a different text like `<br />`. Then you have the content in one line, which you can save via [`fputcsv()`](http://www.php.net/fputcsv). The following example shows how to use `str_replace()`:

```
<?php
$data = "some\r\ncontent\r\nover multiple\r\nlines";
$dataBr = str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", $data);

$fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w+');
fputcsv($fp, array('before', $dataBr, 'after'));
fclose($fp);

echo file_get_contents('test.csv');
```

This will generate the following output:

```
before,"some<br />content<br />over multiple<br />lines",after
```

As you see the new lines (`"\r\n"`) has been replaced by the `<br />` HTML element and the content is in one line.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case.. this only works if I assign the string in my code, but when I assign it via textarea, then "\r\n" won't be found. Perhaps I didn't do it correctly... This is my code based on your solution:


`$f = fopen("../data/forum-data/threads.csv", "a");
                    $data = array($user, $eintrag, $date, time(), $mail);
                    $dataBr = str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", $data);
                    fputcsv($f, $data, ";", chr(127));
                    fclose($f);`

Comment: @cranked_coder You have to change the data before it gets added to the array, not after the array is created (and filled).